# Trying test case Amazon SNS with APNS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Trying to connect java sample code from Amazon [Get started with APNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html) page with APNS. I generated certificates and etc. But getting response shown below. Do I need to configure something at Amazon SNS page before, like Topics, Application or Subscription?

> Error Message:    Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: id-number )

Comment: Hi ,
Did you get any solutions

Comment: Hello, nope. I ask iOS developer to regenerete all certificates and tried to build from fresh sources and it worked. I'm waiting the day when Amazon will let us modify and update API docs.